# In SQLAlchemy, how do I create a 'MySQL date' column?

Tags: mysql, database, date, orm, sqlalchemy

```
class Posts(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'posts_posts'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    user_id = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    body = Column(Text, nullable=True)

    created_at = Column(Date) << is this right?
    updated_at = Column(Date) ??
```

I would also like the `created_at` column to automatically set the date when it's created.
And also, the `updated_at` column to set the date anytime this row is changed.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can provide `default` and `onupdate` parameters to `Column`:

```
def _get_date():
    return datetime.datetime.now()

class Posts(Base):
    #...
    created_at = Column(Date, default=_get_date)
    updated_at = Column(Date, onupdate=_get_date)
```

See [Column](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/core/schema.html?highlight=onupdate#sqlalchemy.schema.Column) documentation for more info on this one.

Comment: There's even easier way: `updated_at = Column(Date, onupdate=datetime.datetime.now)`

Comment: Any tips to how to make `datetime.datetime.now()` timezone aware in SQL Alchemy context?

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa: [`sqlalchemy.types.Datetime`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/types.html?highlight=timezone#sqlalchemy.types.DateTime) takes a parameter `timezone` with default value of `False`.